# Prove that $f(x)=x\sin(x)$ isn't uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-continuity

I want to prove that the following function: $f(x)=x\sin(x)$ isn't uniformly continuous

So, I need to find 2 sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $|x_n-y_n|\to 0$ but $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\geq\epsilon_0$ where $\epsilon_0$ is a positive number (const.).

Any help with this problem? Plus I would be glad if someone could write the solution more formally and clean (I wrote most of it but couldn't find the sequences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

Take
$$x_n=2n^2\pi$$
$$y_n=x_n+\frac 1n$$

it is clear that
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}(y_n-x_n)=0$$
and, by MVT,

$$f(y_n)-f(x_n)=(y_n-x_n)f'(c_n)$$
$$=\frac 1n(\sin(c_n)+c_n\cos(c_n))$$

with
$$2n^2\pi<c_n<2n^2\pi+\frac 1n$$

and
$$2n\pi<\frac{c_n}{n}$$
$$0<\sin(c_n)<\sin(\frac 1n)$$
$$\cos(\frac 1n)<\cos(c_n)<1$$
thus
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(f(y_n)-f(x_n)=+\infty$$

Comment: I just didn't understand why 0<sin()<sin(1) and why cos(1)<cos()<1?the rest is clear

Comment: @dan sin is increasing, cos is decreasing.

Comment: @dan $\sin(2n^2\pi)=0$ and $\cos(2n^2\pi)=1$.